# How unset $_SESSION when refresh page in PHP, AJAX?

Tags: php, ajax, session

I want how destroy/unset the $_SESSION when the user refresh page or enter the website. It's possible?

Comment: A session variable is exactly for keeping it on a reload. Why do you want to do such a thing? But you can use ``session_unset();`` to do exactly that.

Comment: You do realise that a SESSION is unique to one visitor and only that one visitor. When they first visit your site they get their own session.

Answer (score 1):

Add this line to the top of the page on which you wish to unset the session:

```
<?php session_destroy(); ?>
```

[See `session_destroy` on PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-destroy.php)

Answer (score 1):

You can either destroy whole session data through `<?php session_destroy(); ?>` or

```
<?php session_unset(); ?>
```

OR

you can unset particular key through `unset($_SESSION[$key])`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. you can use either php or javascript to unset/destroy session.

If you want to unset only one variable of session array. use :

```
foreach(array_keys($_SESSION) as $k) unset($_SESSION[$k]);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to clear all session simply use

```
session_destroy();
```